# In Spark word count RDD, how to index value for a specific key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD named wc that has (key,value) pairs, where the key is the word, and the value is the count of how many times the word appeared in some document. For example:

```
scala> :type wc
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]

scala> wc.take(10).foreach(println)
(means,1)
(under,2)
(this,4)
(Because,1)
(Python,2)
(agree,1)
(cluster,1)
(its,1)
(follows,1)
(general,2)
```

Without having to print every single pair in the RDD, how could I index this RDD to obtain the count for a specific word (say, Python). I've tried a bunch of things including:

```
wc.filter(_.1 == "Python")
// error: ')' expected but double literal found.
   // wc.filter(_.1 == "Python")

wc.filter(_.2 == "Python")
// error: ')' expected but double literal found.
   // wc.filter(_.2 == "Python")

wc.filter(wc.keys == "Python")
// type mismatch;
   // found   : Boolean
   // required: ((String, Int)) => Boolean
   //       wc.filter(wc.keys == "Python")

wc.filter((k,v) => k == "Python")
// wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
   //       wc.filter((k,v) => k == "Python")
```

I'm not familiar enough with spark syntax to do this, but I think I'm on the right track. Any thoughts appreciated on this - indexing an RDD by its key is a simple yet important operation and I'd like to understand this better.

Thanks in advance!

NOTE - I'm doing this spark coding in SCALA, not python. My class is using SCALA and i am interested in learning SCALAs syntax.

EDIT - The output should be either '2', or (Python, 2), although I'd probably prefer the latter.

Comment: I edited the post with the output I'm expecting - its (Python, 2), which can be seen in the take(10).foreach(println) up top on the post, 5th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is very subtle...you forgot `_` (underscore) in your Scala code.

Instead of `_.1` you should do `_._1`

If you want to access 5th element in `wc`, you could use `RDD.zipWithIndex` operator:

> **zipWithIndex(): RDD[(T, Long)]**
>
> Zips this RDD with its element indices. The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the first partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition receives the largest index.
>
> This is similar to Scala's zipWithIndex but it uses Long instead of Int as the index type. This method needs to trigger a spark job when this RDD contains more than one partitions.

Something like follows should work:

```
scala> wc.zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 == 5).first._1
res0: (String, Int) = (Python,2)
```

Comment: wc.filter(_._1 == "Python").foreach(println)

(Python,2)

Comment: looks good, thanks! is there a better way to print this than doing foreach(println)? since i know it's a unique key, doing a foreach loop seems unnecessary

Comment: If you know that there is only one element after filtering you can use .first() on the RDD to extract the first element. `println(wc.filter(_._1 == "Python").first)`